# Retrieve data/snapshot after manually remove children in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a function that uses `.observeSingleEventOfType` with `.Value` to retrieve data from a subtree from Firebase. The issue I'm facing right now is that, every single time I manually remove children/data in Firebase to test how this function behaves, it always loads the old data the first time when it gets called after deletion. After the first time, it then loads the correct data.

I have tried to use `.ChildAdded` and `.observeEventType`, but the behavior didn't change. I have `Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled` set to `true` now, and I am guessing the problem is that snapshot reads data from cache if it's available, otherwise checks Firebase database.

Any one experiences this kind of issues before?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

UPDATE:
I have tested with and without persistence enabled, it turns out that I was correct, when `Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled` caches all data in the past to memory, and the observe functions will try to load from memory first then go to Firebase.

When I set `Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled = false` The problem went away. However, I would like to have my app work offline as well which mean I do need to set `Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled = true`  Is there a way to have all observe functions cache data except this specific one?

SOLUTION:
The problem is fixed now, the issue was that I didn't remove observers when the view controller was dismissed. So every time I enter the view again, another observer gets called and thus I always receive more than one call backs.

Comment: The question is slightly unclear; are you saying that with your app not running, you use the Firebase dashboard and remove the node in question, then you run the app and the function to observeSingleEvent is called, and it loads the data you deleted in the dashboard?

Comment: No, my app is running fine except every time I delete data in the dashboard, when .observeSingleEvent gets called, it retrieves the old data instead of nil. But the second time and after that when that function gets called, it will then load the correct data which is nil